How to convert a time string measured in 24 hours cycle to 12 hours cycle?
I have a stored value of an hour in a 24-hour format in a variable named hour. My task is to convert this value to a 12-hour format and print the result.
I tried while-loops, if-elif-statements. I changed the value of hours from 24 hour to 12 hour by writing hour = 12.
This was my recent code I tried and still got the answer wrong:
hour = 12

while hour > 12: 
    hour = (hour % 12) + 1

print(hour)

I do not know how this wrong. I added the value of hours to 12. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

You don't need a loop, just if statements.
There are 4 cases you need to handle:

hour == 0 should convert to 12AM
hour < 12 stays the same and gets the AM modifier
hour == 12 converts to 12PM
hour > 12 subtrace 12 and add the PM modifier

if hour == 0:
    print('12AM')
elif hour < 12:
    print(f'{hour}AM')
elif hour == 12:
    print('12PM')
else:
    print(f'{hour-12}PM')


Just using if-statements should be fine. I wrote a mini library just for this purpose, check it out:
def converter(hour, mode=0,AM_or_PM='AM'):
    """ Mode here refers to the 12 hour mode or the 24 hour mode.
    If mode ==0, then it refers to the time given in 12 hour mode, thus converting to military mode (24 hour mode).
    If mode ==1, then it refers to the 24 hour mode, thus converting to standard mode (12 hour mode).
    Must provide the mode argument.

    AM_or_PM here indicates whether a 12-hour cycle time given is AM or PM
    """
    if mode==0:
        if AM_or_PM == 'PM':
            return str(hour+12)
        else:
            return str(hour)
    elif mode == 1:
        if hour ==0:
           return f'12AM'
        elif hour < 12:
           return f'{hour}AM'
        elif hour >= 12:
           return f'{hour}PM'
    return str(hour)

I wrote it as a function with arguments hour (required), mode (semi-required), and AM_or_PM (optional). If mode is provided and is 0, then it means the time should be converted to 24 hour mode. If mode is 1, then it means the time should be converted to 12 hour mode. The rest of the description is provided in the docstring.
However, if you for some reason don't want to use my library, then try to use the datetime library's methods, like this:
import datetime as dt

time1 = dt.datetime(2024, 3, 24, 2, 4, 3, 1).strftime('%H%p')
print(time1)
now = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H%p')
print(now)

Both methods work and are all very convenient to use.
